# Django - Limit the entries in models.ForeignKey()

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is to possible to limit the entries in models.ForeignKey() field based on some condition?

```
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

I just need to show the customer who are in active status.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using the django-admin site, I think you might want the [limit_choices_to](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) option:

i.e.

```
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, limit_choices_to={'active': True})
```